# Override separateSecondaryViewControllerForSplitViewController: for specific UIViewController in monotouch

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, uisplitviewcontroller

I am trying to override the default UINavigationController behavior on separateSecondaryViewControllerForSplitViewController: which is according to  [Apple doc Discussion](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISplitViewControllerDelegate_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UISplitViewControllerDelegate/splitViewController:separateSecondaryViewControllerFromPrimaryViewController:)

> Most view controllers do nothing by default but the UINavigationController class responds by popping and returning the view controller from the top of its navigation stack.

My aim is to:

1. return null from the UISplitViewControllerDelegate.SeparateSecondaryViewController
2. override the default UINavigationController used as primary view controller also
3. => resulting in no secondary view controller (as there is no display mode to get only the primary view controller when split view controller is not collapsed...)

But I can't find any override point in IntelliSense from VS or even when browsing the assembly by reflection, except an extension method which call the method from the selector.

Can I override the default UINavigationController behavior on this point?
If yes, Is it a mistake in the Xamarin API?
Or Is it expected by Xamarin that we have to manually Export the selector?

Perhaps with something like :
`[Export("separateSecondaryViewControllerForSplitViewController:")]
 public UIViewController SeparateSecondaryViewController(UISplitViewController splitViewController)`

NB: I am using Xamarin for VS 3.8.151.0 | Xamarin.iOS 8.4.0.0 ... still a bit worried by the list of known issues since the unified API release :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this method is not correctly bound in `UIViewController` in Xamarin.iOS.

It is an extension method on the `UIKit.UISplitViewController_UIViewController` and defined as:

```
[Export ("separateSecondaryViewControllerForSplitViewController:"), Availability (Introduced = Platform.iOS_8_0), CompilerGenerated]
public static UIViewController SeparateSecondaryViewControllerForSplitViewController (this UIViewController This, UISplitViewController splitViewController);
```

You should be able to put the method into your view controller subclass like this:

```
[Export ("separateSecondaryViewControllerForSplitViewController:")]
public UIViewController SeparateSecondaryViewControllerForSplitViewController (UISplitViewController splitViewController)
{
  return null; // return whatever you need to return
}
```

Exporting it manually should do the trick. Let me know if it works.

Comment: `separateSecondaryViewControllerForSplitViewController:` is defined by `UIViewController` so inherited (and overridden) by `UINavigationController`

Comment: Hmm...see this; maybe it helps; to me it looks like you're right and the methods is not surfaced in Xamarin.iOS: http://iosapi.xamarin.com/index.aspx?link=M%3AUIKit.UISplitViewController_UIViewController.SeparateSecondaryViewControllerForSplitViewController(UIKit.UIViewController%2CUIKit.UISplitViewController)

Comment: I tried to define the export myself and it worked well (I mean my implementation was called)... But I have not been able to achieve my aim this way (no secondary view controller when my UISplitViewController got separated on traits changed).

I have given up on this as it seems not really expected by Apple implementation and I did not want to subclass UISplitViewController only for this, I just wanted a delegate.

Mark your reply as answered as it solves my first issue, thanks for the helps :)